# Symfony 4 - Webpack-encore use FosJsRouting : Routing is not defined

Tags: symfony, routes, defined, webpack-encore

I try to use FosJsRouting with Webpack-encore in my Symfony 4 project.

I did :

1.

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle
```

2.

```
php bin/console assets:install --symlink public
```

3.

```
php bin/console fos:js-routing:dump --format=json --target=public/js/fos_js_routes.json
```

And in my **app.js** :

```
// FosJsRouting

const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';
Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
```

Now, if in the **app.js** I do a `console.log(Routing);` I get the object in the console.

On the other hand, impossible to use it in my templates.

I have the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Routing is not defined

I do not understand because my other packages work very well, but not the Routing

Answer (score 7):

You may have found the solution but here are some information for the others:

- The files are isolated that's why a variable which is defined from import/require in a file is undefined in another or in your templates even if you include the file in your template.

## 1. Import and configure everywhere

So, inside your `app.js`, where you import `Routing`, it can only be used in this specific file and you must import it wherever you want it. But, you need to set the routes everytime:

**app.js**

```
const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';
Routing.setRoutingData(routes);

console.log(Routing.generate("exposed_route_name")); // will prints in console /path/to/exposed_route
```

**other.js**

```
const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';
Routing.setRoutingData(routes);

console.log(Routing.generate("another_exposed_route_name")); // will prints in console /path/to/another_exposed_route
```

It is not a proper solution because it too redundant and nobody wants to duplicate the same code everytime.

---

## 2. Globalize `Routing` variable

Another solution is setting `Routing` as **global** and access it in files included after:

**app.js**

```
const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';
Routing.setRoutingData(routes);

// Setting Routing as global there
global.Routing = Routing;

console.log(Routing.generate("exposed_route_name")); // will prints in console /path/to/exposed_route
```

**other.js**

```
console.log(Routing.generate("another_exposed_route_name")); // will prints in console /path/to/another_exposed_route
```

**template.html.twig**

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('other') }}

<script>
console.log(Routing.generate("a_third_exposed_route_name")); // will prints in console /path/to/third_exposed_route
</script>
```

The problem is that Routing will be available everywhere when the file which globalize it is included. It will be available in your web console too and I don't think it is a good thing because everyone will be able to see all your fos_js_routing configuration.

---

## 3. Export `Routing` in your own module

And there is the solution for which you create a "fake" Routing module. In this file, you will set your Routing object configuration and export it:

**routing.js**

```
const routes = require("../../public/js/fos_js_routes");
const Routing = require("../../public/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router"); // do not forget to dump your assets `symfony console assets:install --symlink public`

Routing.setRoutingData(routes);

module.exports = Routing;
```

And then import it in whatever file to use it:

**other.js**

```
const Routing = import("./routing");
console.log(Routing.generate("another_exposed_route_name")); // will prints in console /path/to/another_exposed_route
```

You don't need to setting `routing.js` as a webpack entry nor including it in your templates. However, I don't know how to do it if you write your javascript directly in your twig templates.

Hope you will find your solution. You can also check this [tutorial](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore-legacy/fos-js-routing-bundle) on SymfonyCasts.

Comment: This should be the documentation on the actual bundle. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! For solution 3, I had to change `import` by `require` in "other.js" file : `const Routing = require("./routing");`

Answer (score -1):

**Globalise Routing variable** is solution to use in javascript with webpack installation

In **app.js**

```
const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';
Routing.setRoutingData(routes);

// Setting Routing as global there
global.Routing = Routing;

console.log(Routing.generate("exposed_route_name"));
```